# How to find the minimum and maximum element from queue?

Tags: c#, queue

I am making application using c#. I have one queue as follows...

```
Queue QueueData = new Queue(60);
```

I want to find the min and max element from that queue. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using a queue if you have such a requirement?

Comment: I am taking Queue because of every single operation i am adding value from one side and removing from other side.So In such condition Queue is efficient.

Comment: But not for finding `Min` and `Max`.

Comment: In every operation i am adding 4 values in Queue and finding again min and max value from that Queue.So

Comment: How bout you simply keep a variable outside that stores the maximum value of any element being enqueued? Any other way will require you to dequeues every element, find the max / max and enqueue them again. You could use the linq methods, but they too will prove inefficient..

Comment: Do you know ahead of time that the queue is guaranteed to be small?  If the queue is going to grow large then you'll need to use special techniques to find the minimum and maximum efficiently.  Can you describe in more details precisely how you are going to use this queue?  If for example you intend to dequeue the minimum item rather than the oldest item, then the data structure you want is called a "priority queue"; priority queues use special data structures so that they stay efficient even when large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use linq `Min` and `Max` methods.

Convert your `Queue` to `Queue<T>` and look here for examples:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Aggregate-Operators-c51b3869

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use LINQ in such cases?(Specially for QUEUE)

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you must specify what value you want the max and min values of:

```
var max = QueueData.Max(x => x.SomeSelectedComparableValue);
var min = QueueData.Min(x => x.SomeSelectedComparableValue);
```

Comment: ... which he did not specify, and therefore I did not assume.

Comment: If Dany doesn't know about `Min` and `Max` methods then he can't put in the question something relevant to the answer. Also, if someone else looks at your answer they may assume that you always 'must' specify the member.

Comment: If Dany has such limited knowledge, your original answer wasn't any helpful at all... My 2 cents.